# Unity SteamVR disable HTC vive HMD tracking

Tags: unity-game-engine, htc-vive

I'm trying to render two static cameras to the HMD, one for each eye. So Cam (Left) renders to the left eye and Cam (right) renders to the right eye. The problem that I have now is that Cam (Left) and Cam (Right) follow the HMD position and rotation. I tryed a few things but they don't work the cameras keep tracking and the HMD movements and move accordingly. Is there a way to disable the HMD tracking?

Already tryed:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/completely-disable-position-tracking.450644/ (The cameras still move a little and they are moved to the center of the world when you run the game)

https://github.com/guiglass/StationaryStereoCamera (This make it possible to render images to the HMD that don't move when you move the HMD. This soulution can work if I can render the whole camera view from Cam (Left) and Cam (Right) and keep them from moving)

Thx in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do this, for anyone who has the same problem:

Attaching a Tracked Pose Driver to the camera, and disabling should effectively disable head tracking.